# Should I use headphones when I have hearing loss?

Tags: hearing, hearing-impaired, congenital, earplugs-earphones, noise-induce-hearing-harm

I googled this query but all I got was that loud music on headphones causes hearing loss.Now I use headphones sometimes and I had hearing impairment from when I was a kid.Should I altogether stop using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have sensorineural hearing loss and regularly use headphones, you might be listening to a louder volume than if you did not have hearing loss.  This may mean you could be subjecting your hearing apparatus to potentially damaging thresholds.

Hearing aids are not just fancy headphones. They are sophisticated aural rehabilitation devices that are tuned to an individual's hearing loss. New, digital hearing aids also have other advanced technologies such as directional sound detection, filtering, among many others.

Credibility: I am an ENT. The above post does not constitute medical advice.

Answer (score 0):

Headphones are just a "small" speaker that is close to your ear. In terms of acoustics, it doesn't mater if a sound is generated by headphones, a speaker, or someone talking/yelling/singing/banging pots. What does matter is how loud the sound is, the frequency content, and the duration you listen.

There is no reason to stop using headphones. In fact, hearing aids are just fancy headphones. There is some evidence that you should limit your exposure to loud and prolonged sounds, but that is a different question.